# Can I decompile any game which is written in C# or any other language through java decompiler tool?

Tags: java, c#, reverse-engineering, decompiler

There are lots of game which are made using Unity 3d or unreal game engine. I am able to decompile an apk which is made from android studio but i don't know whether it works in those games because I don't even know from which software they had been made or which language they had been written.

Can I easily decompile them too using java decompilers or do I have to use any other method (I don't know any other method more than of java. If there is any, please tell).

By the way, and for detail, I want to decompile **mad dex** android game.

Comment: Separately from how feasible it is, please consider the *legality* of doing this, which may well depend on your country - and the *morality* of doing this, which doesn't. (If the developer wanted you to be able to see the source code, they would presumably have provided it for you.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A decompiler for Java decompiles JVM bytecode. It has no idea what CLR bytecode (the one used by C#) looks like.

So to answer your question: no, you can't use a decompiler made for Java to decompile something that is not meant to be run on a JVM. You'll have to find a decompiler for CLR bytecode.